# apply ordering on limit query of active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I need to find 10 records first and then apply ordering on that.

```
Model.all.limit(10).order('cast(code as integer)')
```

result of above code is - first it applies order on model and then limit query. So, I get same codes in my listing for given model. But I want to apply limit query first and then order fetched result.

Comment: why do you want to add the limit first and then ordering ? because you want a random sample?

Comment: i think you can try like this `@model = Model.all.limit(10)` and `@model.order('cast(code as integer)')`

Comment: Something.find(:all, :limit => 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.all` on model, it executes the query on DB and returns all records, to apply `limit` you have to write it before `.all` - `Model.limit(10).all`, but after that you can't use SQL function to operate data. So to get first 10 records and apply order to it, try this:

`records = Model.limit(10).all.sort_by{|o| o.code.to_i}`

or

`records = Model.first(10).sort_by{|o| o.code.to_i}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Model.limit(10).sort{|p, q| q.cost <=> p.cost}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to remove the `.all` method:

```
Model.limit(10).order('cast(code as integer)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 10 random records and then sort them without getting all records from the database then you could use

```
Model.limit(10).order("RANDOM()")
```

This uses the PostgreSQL rand() function to randomise the records.

Now you have an array of 10 random records and you can use .sort_by as described by BitOfUniverse.